# Laravel blade - show fa-icon dependable on file type

Tags: laravel-blade

I have this foreach loop to list out all the files

```
@foreach ($event->event_files as $f => $file)
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="{{\Storage::disk('public')->url($file->path)}}">{{$file->name}}</a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

And what i want to make is a preview icon for every file so that it looks like this:

[image]

I have the icons and i have the file type extensions....i just don't know how to connect all of this in a foreach loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make array in controller:

```
$icons = [
        'pdf' => 'pdf',
        'doc' => 'word',
        'docx' => 'word',
        'xls' => 'excel',
        'xlsx' => 'excel',
        'ppt' => 'powerpoint',
        'pptx' => 'powerpoint',
        'txt' => 'text',
        'png' => 'image',
        'jpg' => 'image',
        'jpeg' => 'image',
    ];
```

and send it to view with

```
return view('edit', compact('icons'));
```

and in blade

```
@foreach ($event->event_files as $f => $file)
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
     <i class="fa fa-file-{{$icons[$file->type]}}-o fa-5x text-center"/></i>

     <div class="clearfix"></div>

     <a href="{{\Storage::disk('public')->url($file->path)}}">{{$file->name}}</a>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

and you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: hmm nice...except my filetypes are extensions and they don't match the fa-icons namings....i will need to change that

Comment: yes, may be you need a key-value array , to convert you extension according font icon name.

Comment: i'm thinking to make a new column in my DB just for fa-icon so when i save the file it saves the naming for that icon, and then i can call `$file->icon` in blade....but i'm open for any better ideas...What do you think?

Comment: I don't think its a good way. Map your file extension to font name is more easy, and more agile from the icon name change.

Comment: How do you mean that? I already have the extension. But the extensions are like 'pdf',  'txt', 'jpeg', 'doc', 'xlsx' and the fa-icon namings are 'word' 'excel', 'powerpoint' how can i map that?

Comment: ['pdf' => 'pdf', 'doc' => 'word'];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129989/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-kris-roofe).